# How to optimise creating histogram bins in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, histogram, binning

I want to group integers, e.g. epoch time values, into equal sized bins, e.g. 5, in SQLite.

i.e turning this:

```
geolocation table:
+-------+
| time  |
+-------+
| 0     |
| 0     |
| 0     |
| ...   |
| 46801 |
| 46801 |
| ...   |
| 46802 |
| ...   |
+-------+
```

into this:

```
query result:
+-------+-------+
| bin   | count |
+-------+-------+
| 0     | 134   |
| 46800 | 400   |
| 46805 | 223   |
| 46810 | 161   |
| ...   | ...   |
+-------+-------+
```

I can achieve this using the following query:

```
select bin, count(*) as count from (
    select cast(time/5.00 as int)*5 as bin
    from geolocation
    order by time
)
group by 1;
```

However when the `geolocation` table is 4 million rows big, this query took about 1.3 seconds to execute. The inner query on its own is very fast so most of the time taken I assume is executing the outer query.

Assuming that the `time` field in `geolocation` table is indexed, is there a way to optimise this query?

Because since the inner query already returns sorted values, isn't it straightforward for the outer query to repeatedly binary search distinct values and get the count for each distinct value? (I am not sure how `group by` works under the hood). Using such an approach should take O(log n) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

> ... since the inner query already returns sorted values, isn't it
> straightforward for the outer query to repeatedly binary search
> distinct values and get the count for each distinct value?

An `ORDER BY` clause inside a subquery is useless.
It is not guaranteed that the outer query will process the rows returned by the subquery in that particular order.

In your case, you can simplify your code to this:

```
SELECT time/5*5 AS bin, 
       COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM geolocation
GROUP BY bin;
```

Assuming that the data type of `time` is `INTEGER`, the expression:

```
cast(time/5.00 as int)*5
```

can be written as:

```
time/5*5
```

because SQLite performs integer division when both operands are integers.

Or, you can try with `COUNT(*)` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT time/5*5 AS bin,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY time/5*5) AS count 
FROM geolocation;
```